# TwitterのiOSアプリのプロフィール画面の実装

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, twitter

全体は、UITableViewで、「ツイート」 「ツイートと返信」などはSection、
その下は、UIContainerViewでTableViewを管理しているのだと予想していますが、
どのようにして、UITableViewの中のTableViewのスクロールを干渉しないように実現させているのでしょうか？

[image: Twitter]

Answer (score 1):

サクッとつくってみました

[image: Twitter Like UI]
前提として、Twitterの中がどうなってるのかはわかりません。
世界的なアプリはビックリするような実装してたりするので。

似たようなUIをどう作るかですが、私が考えた流れを書いてみます。

・同じScroll方向の入れ子はあまり現実的ではありません（経験上）、
 特に２つでスクロール量をコンバートするのは本当に危険です（非常に難しい）
 というわけで縦のスクロールは恐らく１つです
・４つのViewはTableViewだと思います、エンドレスでスクロールできますから
・4つのTableViewは横ScrollViewで管理されていると思います
 PageViewControllerも考えられますが、PageViewControllerの場合は、Viewを遷移したときに読み込みが走ります、Twitterは先に読込されています
 （スマニューなんかと比べてみてください、あちらはPageViewControllerだと思います）
・ヘッダーは4つのTableViewに影響して動いています。
 つまりどのViewにも属していなくて、self.Viewの下に存在しています（ここが罠ですね）
・ヘッダーはTableViewのcontentOffsetに応じて動きます
 ヘッダーのTopConstraintを、scrollViewDidScrollから動かしてあげれば割と簡単です
・TableViewの上の方はヘッダーに隠れてしまうため、contentInsetで上を開けてやります

分かってしまうと、意外とトリッキーなことしてなさそうですねこれ

ソースコードを置いておきます
https://github.com/osanaikoutarou/TwitterLikeUI

ちなみに、雑に作ってるのでTableViewをスクロールしたあとで横に切り替えるとヘッダーの位置がおかしくなります
本家を触ってみると、結構細かな仕様が隠れてそうです（4つのスクロール位置の取り扱い）

Comment: ありがとうございます！
ぜひコードを参考にさせていただきたいのですが、
GitHubにコードが反映されていないので、
上げていただけるととても嬉しいです

Comment: すいませんうっかりadd忘れてました、今pushしたところです